# URL's in search results page are wrong and not the URL of the article assigned menu item

Tags: sef, seo, search, com-search

I have Joomla 3.9.21 which has SEF URL's enabled.

All works perfectly, except for the search results page.

For example, this is the SEO link to an article (which is assigned a menu option whose root option is called "proyectos"):

```
https://www.example.com/proyectos/thearticle.html
```

So far, so good. However, when I do a search where that article is on the results, the link of the article is this:

```
https://www.example.com/component/content/article/thearticle.html?catid=13&Itemid=101
```

How can I get rid of the `component/content/article` part and replace it by the menu option the article is assigned to? In this case, root menu option is called "proyectos".

If I disable SEF, I realized that this URL is for the menu option that is assigned to the article:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15&Itemid=160
```

And when searching, this is the actual URL for that article on the results page:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15:thearticle&catid=13&Itemid=101
```

Maybe the `Itemid=101` part is interfering. `Itemid` 101 is the home menu item. This ID is strange. For some reason, com_search module is not finding the Itemid associated to the article, 160 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the problem is about the language. I have menu and articles with Spanish language. Only Home menu item is for All languages.

I changed the article menu item for All languages, and it worked. The right Itemid is being retrieved now.

Is this a bug or is there some workaround when working with site languages?